# db2 database gui interface

Tags: database, db2, sqlclient

Which database client tool (gui tool), can be used to view/modify the user permissions in a db2 database. The version is db2 v 11.1.

control center is discontinued as per the notes in publib. Installed squirrel sql, but not able to see a place/tool where we can grant/revoke permissions of a db user?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions in Db2 are stored in the [catalog](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008443.html?pos=2). You can learn more about the [Db2 security model](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0021804.html) from this part of the documentation. Giving a user permissions or deleting them is done via the `GRANT` and `REVOKE` statements. To find out which permissions exist, you can query the related catalog views.

IBM has two tools which provide a UI to those catalog entries and help with user management. These are [IBM Data Studio](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ibm-data-studio) and [IBM Data Server Manager (DSM)](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/data-server-manager).